# Add label with mean value of y-axis variable to geom_point in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, mean

I have the following code (see below). I want to add the mean value of the variable *value* as a label to the points in the chart. Any suggestions? 
Thanks for your help! :)

```
df_1 <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B","C"),3),value=rnorm(9))

ggplot(df_1,aes(x=group,y=value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.1) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `stat_summary`:

```
ggplot(df_1,aes(x=group,y=value)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.1) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point") +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="label", aes(label = round(..y.., 2)), hjust = -0.1)
```

Or `geom_label`:

```
ggplot(df_1,aes(x=group,y=value)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.1) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point") +
    geom_label(stat = 'summary', fun.y=mean, aes(label = round(..y.., 2)), nudge_x = 0.1, hjust = 0)
```

Comment: ... just one more thing. When you execute the code, the labels have a black frame around them. Any way to remove that frame?

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_text` instead of `geom_label`?